# Exec <script> without eval() with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I get a JSON from my server. I have do all my HTML and a tag script from this json. The problem is that my HTML doesn't exec my tag `<script>`. If I use `eval();` yes, but I can't use `eval()` for security.

I tried with `innerHtml`, con `insertAdj`, the last body, with `onload` etc...

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html class="no-js" lang="es">
    <head>

    <script src="elementos.js"></script>
    <script src="transform.js"></script>

    <script>
        function transform(){
            cargarMulti();
        }
    </script>
</head>
 <body class="spp-loading" onload="transform();">
    <main class="spp-main">
        <article id="zona_despliegue">
        </article>
    </main>
    <div id="transform">
    </div>
</body>
```

You can see my HTML have only tag `article`, `<div id="transform">` and `onload`.

Now my `function transform(){}` call to server to get my JSON, then I created the HTML elements `inputs`, `labels`, etc. Finally I created the `<script>`.

**Example:**

```
cargarMulti(); // call to transform.js

function cargarMulti(){

    // perform JSON validation process
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "./entrada", true);
    request.send(null);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
            var MyJSON = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            procesar(MyJSON);
        }
    }
}
}
```

**transform.js**

```
function procesar(JSON) {
    var cadenaScript = generarScriptAsistente(JSON);
    var div = document.getElementById("transform");
    div.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', cadenaScript);

    var cadena = procesarComponenteMultiProductoAsistente(JSON.pasos);
    cadena += abrirDivConId("js-spp-assistant") + cerrarDiv();
    document.getElementById(JSON.areaCarga).innerHTML += cadena;

    /*
     * document.getElementById(JSON.areaCarga).innerHTML+=cadena; var ele =
     * document.getElementById(JSON.areaCarga); var
     * codes=document.getElementsByTagName("script"); for(var i=0;i<codes.length;i++){
     * eval(codes[i].text); }
     */
}

// This is a fragment, `cadenaScript` write in html all `<script>`.
// cadena write in html all HTML elements inputs, labels etc.
```

when I execute the program, it doesn't run. If I inspect `F12`, I can see all elements only run with `eval()`, but I can't use `eval()`. Thanks!

[image]

## Edit:

[image]

**Json** from server:

```
"areaCarga": "zona_despliegue",
    "pasos": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "titulo": "Te ayudamos",
                "subtitulo": "Elije",
                "tituloSelector": "",
                "textoTag1": "Personal",
                "textoTag2": "Pareja",
                "textoTag3": "Familia",
                "textoTag4": "",
                "textoTag5": "",
                "iconoTag1": "spp-ico-user",
                "iconoTag2": "spp-ico-users",
                "iconoTag3": "spp-ico-group",
                "iconoTag4": "",
                "iconoTag5": "",
                "tag1": "user",
                "tag2": "users",
                "tag3": "group",
                "tag4": "",
                "tag5": "",
                "botonNext": "Continuar",
                "botonBack": "",
                "tituloEnlaces": "",
                "tituloRelacionado": ""
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "titulo": "Te ayudamos",
                "subtitulo": "Elije",
                "tituloSelector": "",
                "textoTag1": "Hogar",
                "textoTag2": "Salud",
                "textoTag3": "",
                "textoTag4": "",
                "textoTag5": "",
                "iconoTag1": "spp-ico-house",
                "iconoTag2": "spp-ico-healthcare",
                "iconoTag3": "",
                "iconoTag4": "",
                "iconoTag5": "",
                "tag1": "home",
                "tag2": "health",
                "tag3": "car",
                "tag4": "future",
                "tag5": "money",
                "botonNext": "Continuar",
                "botonBack": "Volver",
                "tituloEnlaces": "",
                "tituloRelacionado": ""
            } 
    ],
    "productos": [
        {
            "titulo": "Zero",
            "entrada": "ZERO",
            "imagen": "./images/cuentas.jpg",
            "enlace": "",
            "tags": ["user", "home", "unification"]
        },
        {
            "titulo": "ONE",
            "entrada": "ONE",
            "imagen": "./images/cuenta-ONE.jpg",
            "enlace": "",
            "tags": ["user", "home", "unification"]
        }
    ],
    "enlaces": [
        {
            "titulo": "ABCD",
            "referencia": ""
        },
        {
            "titulo": "EFGH",
            "referencia": ""
        }
    ],
    "pieEnlace": {
        "titulo": "Buscador",
        "referencia": ""
    }
}
```

Comment: add your script tag below your markup or add an window.onload = //do your stuff

Comment: Add this call *cargarMulti();* to be right above your </body> tag.  ( remove the call from the header ).

Comment: As I understand, you create content of a script tag after receiving JSON. But after that you're not able to execute it. Right? So why not to create function, where you may pass your JSON, so it could process this input data and do what you need. Calling this function after receiving JSON is not a problem and it'll work.

Comment: You are using some internal library/framework (based on the Spanish function names everywhere) which is just unknown to outsiders.

Comment: example, pls ? I added inside from script> in my header window.onload = function() {
    sppWizard.init(optionsAssistant);
    }; but it doesnt run

Comment: I don't use library/framework

Comment: @Anarion, I get a Json from my server, I created all html, then I need execute this script with -> sppWizard.init(optionsAssistant);

Comment: Can you show `generarScriptAsistente`?

Comment: What makes you think running script automatically _not_ using `eval` is safer than using `eval`?

Comment: @JamesThorpe Hi, when I use eval(), this program runs, but my boss says " eval() is forbidden with fortify". Sorry for my English.

Comment: script> Have 2 thing-- 1, my var with datas from JSON, and  sppWizard.init(optionsAssistant); for execute this. But now I used windows.onload, for frist comment, but nothing

Comment: `function transform()` and `<div id="transform">` may have some visibility clashes (HTML elements with `id`-s become implicit JavaScript variables). Can you try what happens if you rename one of them?